# MySQL auto-store datetime for each row

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, audit

In MySQL, I'm sick of adding the columns `dt_created` and `dt_modified` (which are date time stamps for creation and last modified respectively) to all the tables I have in my database.

Every time I `INSERT` or `UPDATE` the database, I will have to use the `NOW()` keyword. This is going all over my persistence.

Is there any efficient alternative where MySQL can automatically store at least the datatime of the row that is inserted and let me retrieve it?

Comment: My poor grammar lurks on the dark depths of Stack Overflow. Thank you @Eric Leschinski.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can use DEFAULT constraints to set the timestamp:

```
ALTER TABLE
 MODIFY dt_created datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

ALTER TABLE
 MODIFY dt_modified datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Then you wouldn't have to specify `NOW()` in your INSERT/UPDATE statements.

Reference: [TIMESTAMP properties](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)

Comment: ahh I didn't know you can use something like `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: **Aditional info:** One TIMESTAMP column in a table can have the current timestamp as the default value for initializing the column, as the auto-update value, or both. It is not possible to have the current timestamp be the default value for one column and the auto-update value for another column. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: `DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is not valid SQL. It must be either `dt_modified datetime ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `dt_modified datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` If you still claim it is valid, then perhaps MySQL Workbench has a problem with it that should be mentioned.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using **phpmyadmin** you can do this by :

[image]

Answer (score 11):

```
ALTER TABLE  `tablename` CHANGE  `dt`  `dt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

should be the correct code.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can't have both:

[mysql doc:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

> It is not possible to have the current timestamp be the default value for one column and the auto-update value for another column.

Sad, isn't it?

You could however use null instead of now() [following this tip](http://gusiev.com/2009/04/update-and-create-timestamps-with-mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

Similar question was asked here "[Timestamp for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920796/row-versioning-for-mysql)" the timestamp field will update every time it is accessed. You might also consider a [Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) placed on the table in question to automatically populate those fields for you. Depending on the environment some shops/businesses do not like the use of triggers and so you might have to find alternate work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

In phpmyadmin you can set
[image]

OR 
use this query

```
ALTER TABLE  `tablename`
    CHANGE  `dt_created`  `dt_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

could be set as default an on update of rows

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `dt` `dt` TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```