# How to fix PHP: Notice: Undefined index: columnname from a Form action "INSERT INTO"

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to figure out what went wrong to my codes, basically, I'm just trying to create an "insert data" modal to my PHP homework. I have a database name sampleDB and these data are supposed to go to the table named "con_tab".

I'm using XAMPP for my homework.

The database:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sampleDB");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

The modal's header where I catch errors:

```
<?php 
require('../config/Database.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM con_tab";

$status = "";
if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
{ 
$contitle = $_REQUEST['con_title']; 
$conauth = $_REQUEST['con_auth'];
$condstart = $_REQUEST['con_dstart'];
$condcomp = $_REQUEST['con_dcomp'];
$conabs = $_REQUEST['con_abs'];
$concol = $_REQUEST['con_col'];
$constat = $_REQUEST['con_stat'];
$moddate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");    

$ins_query="INSERT INTO con_tab (con_title,con_auth,con_dstart,con_dcomp,con_abs,con_col,con_stat) VALUES ('$contitle', '$conauth', '$condstart', '$condcomp', '$conabs', '$concol', '$constat', '$moddate')";

mysqli_query($conn,$ins_query) or die(mysql_error());
$status = "New data successfully added.</br></br></a>";
}
?>
```

Here's the error messages:

> Notice: Undefined index: con_title in
>   C:\xampp..\con-modal.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: con_auth in
>   C:\xampp..\con-modal.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined index: con_dstart in
>   C:\xampp..\con-modal.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined index: con_dcomp in
>   C:\xampp..\con-modal.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined index: con_abs in
>   C:\xampp..\con-modal.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Undefined index: con_col in
>   C:\xampp..\con-modal.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Undefined index: con_stat in
>   C:\xampp..\con-modal.php on line 15

In which the lines 9-15 starts at $contitle to $con_stat. This post was tagged as duplicate but the link given didn't solve the problem I have, the issues are different.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439) Besides you have it wrong with `mysql_error`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: It seems like you do not submit the parameters you try to access, neither with GET nor with POST. What is `var_dump($_REQUEST)`?

Comment: Please count your column and inserted column and Insert query recheck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is so much wrong with your code:

But, your issue is caused by your `$_REQUEST`ed parameters not being present; they have not been give to the script.

So; you have three options:
You need to check your HTML form to ensure that the correct parameter names have been given, *or* you need to check each `$_REQUEST` with an `if(isset(...))` wrapper *or* you can simply ignore this error.

Example 1:

HTML:

```
  <input type='text' value='something' name='con_title'>
                                 Check HERE  ^^^^^^^^^
```

Example 2:

```
$contitle = "";
if(isset($_REQUEST['con_title'])){
    $contitle = $_REQUEST['con_title'];
}
```

Example 3:

[Php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [per script](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
```

---

## Other issues:

- You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).
- It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it will potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)
- You do not need brackets around your `require` or `include` statements.
- `$_POST['new']==1` is open to abuse; you should use `===` as much as possible. Use `$_POST['new'] === "1"` (posted values are always strings)
- Best practise, do not add time's to the SQL when you write the INSERT; instead it's more profficient to set the [MySQL column to be a Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932093/mysql-auto-store-datetime-for-each-row) and set

  ```
   ALTER TABLE con_tab MODIFY moddate datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ```
- Count your insert columns and insert data, you are currently inserting more data than you have set columns. This will fail.
- Correct your HTML syntax. You want `<br/>` not `</br>`. You seem to have an excess `</a>` for some reason, too.
- It is better to use `$_POST` throughout rather than `$_REQUEST` as `$_REQUEST` will potentially also accept cookie data or other data that is non-`POST`ed.